# make data no-editable but remain readable on a click of button in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner and successfully connected a php page with mysql. the page displays fields for users to edit/enter data. Now I want to provide users a button at the click of this button, the user can no longer edit the data but can see without any difficulty.
I dont want to use locking table since there may be other data from other pages that has to be edited.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Sure. I have a php page which is connected with mysql database and display fields and let the users to enter the data. I want to add a button, once the user entered all required fields, then want him to click the button after which the data in the field becomes uneditable but he can see the data entered.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `readonly="readonly"` to all your input elements, or disable your form by adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to your form element.

Comment: Note that these are only polite suggestions from the browser; a determined user may turn these off and still submit form POSTs. So be sure to check server-side first before inserting any data.

Comment: Yes I am looking for server-side solution not on client side